# Pull request from local to remote on the same branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I am working with bitbucket. I have made changes to a particular branch on my local machine. Is it possible to make a pull request on the same branch?  I have not found anyway to do it just yet but I would like to basically push code, that is then reviewed by a 3rd party before it makes its way into the remote repo.

Comment: On a fork, or the original repo? If the latter, then: no.

Comment: Parent, so I guess that answers my question. Sorry I am still learning about git. Appreciate the help.